# Getting the content by regular expresssion c#

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to take the content from the next string:

```
value="/wEPDwULLTE5OTI3MDk2NTMPZBYEAgEPZBYCAgUPFgIeB....>
```

How can i get everything between "value=" and ">"?

Thanks

Comment: You must have forgotten to post what you tried?

Comment: What is the tag `nsregularexpression` doing here?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this pattern:

```
value="([^>]*)>
```

For example:

```
string input = "value=\"/wEPDwULLTE5OTI3MDk2NTMPZBYEAgEPZBYCAgUPFgIeB....>";
var output = Regex.Match(input, "value=\"([^>]*)>").Value;
Console.WriteLine(output); // /wEPDwULLTE5OTI3MDk2NTMPZBYEAgEPZBYCAgUPFgIeB....
```

Comment: It is working! Thanks :). Can you explain why is it working? Why did you put "([^]*)" and then once again ">" ?

Comment: @Yoyoyo `([^>]*)` will match any character except `>`. `([^>]*)>` means 'everything, up to the first `>`'. Welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer works solved your original problem, please accept it. It helps others know that your problem was resolved. Also, in the future, to avoid down-votes, please post what you've tried and why it failed in your question.